# Vbulletin Authentication Issues Constantly losing session

Tags: session, authentication, vbulletin

I have a Vbulletin forum which somewhat randomly seems to be losing session authentication information somehow. I log into the site directly from home page as admin and navigate to another page, and all appears like i never logged in, the login information is missing.  Has anyone else experienced this problem with vbulletin. Im running VB5 Connect.

Cheers
V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe after a long time of trial and error that there must be an issue with the way the my Elastic Load Balancer was configured.  I had been hosting the vbulletin service on EC2 behind an ELB.  I now have the site setup directly by the server IP without load balancing and seems to be working ok.  Unfortunately I was not able to get any information from the people at vbulletin so i've now beefed up the server and left it without load balancing.    Perhaps something for someone else if they encounter this.

Cheers